# how to increase selection area of a click in javascript/SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

It's been 3 years since this was last discussed so I hope something has improved in the interim. I'm writing a simple drawing tool in javascript using SVG. I want the lines drawn to be selectable so each polyline has an onclick attribute. But it's almost impossible to select a 1 px wide line. You've got to have the cursor spot on. Is there some way to increase the area either around the line or (better) increase the selection area around the cursor? The only solution in the past was to draw a fat invisible line behind every thin line and respond to clicks on that but that's pretty awkward. Is there a better way?

Comment: I can't give you the specifics, but it might be an option to use a single click event handler on the svg element then you some sort of coordinate system to determine what was clicked using your own predefined rules

Comment: I think using a fat invisible line is the good way. A larger area around the line which listen for events to apply to this line.

Comment: I have dealt with this problem in the past with, as @Gael suggested, creating a separate element that is invisible which houses the handler. The invisible element needs to be later in the <svg> code so it's on top. In practice, I've packaged the two together in a <g> for some Angular directives.